# Interpretation of Hochschild Homology groups

Tags: homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, hochschild-cohomology, hochschild-homology, homological-dimension

In all the literature I've come across there are many concrete interpretations of the first few Hochschild Cohomology groups.  For example $HH^1(A,M)\cong Derivation/Inner Derivations$ etc....

In contrast I have only ever seen the $0^{th}$ Hochschild homology groups' interpretation....

My question is are the other interpretations of $HH_1(A,M)$, $HH_2(A,M)$,... known?
If so what are they and where can these papers be found?

Comment: Isn't this briefly discussed in Weibel's book?

Comment: No he discusses the HKR, when A is commutative

Comment: OK, probably I have misremembered. I know he does 1st and 2nd degree cohomology.

Answer (score 1):

We have $HH_0(A,M)=M/[A,M]$, the largest quotient of $M$ on which the left and the right action agree. $HH_1(A,M)$ can be identified with Kaehler Differential forms $M\otimes_A\Omega(A/k)$. This is for example spelled out [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hochschild+cohomology) or [here](http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/schweigert/ss11/Hochschild.pdf).

Comment: I believe your second statement is only true if the $k$algebra $A$ is commutative...

Comment: Sorry, I was only looking at that. I think one point of view is to define generalized differential forms as Hochschild homology (the Hochschild-Konstant-Rosenberg theorem justifies that). Even in the non-commutative case, the relation for a 2-boundary looks similar to the Leibniz rule: $a\cdot d(bc)=ab⋅d(c)+ca⋅d(b)$, where I just write the second tensor as d(−).